# Typescript / Mocha Test Framework: Initialization code to block and wait for a promise

Tags: typescript, async-await, mocha.js

I am working on a suite of API tests. Right now, I believe that Typescript and Mocha are the best choice for that. However, I am running into one issue: Before the API tests run, I need some initialization code that will authenticate with some external systems to create some test fixtures and do authentication.

That needs to happen *before* any test starts.

My plan was to do this via a mocha require `mocha -r initializer.ts src/test/**/*.ts`.

That works well so far. However, the challenge I am facing is, that I need to do a lot of HTTP API calls in that initializer. I am using an API client, that is async and uses Promises. This is issue, because I need to ensure that tests are not started, before initializer.ts has done it's work.

Is there any way (except for a busy loop) I could make this work?

Answer (score 0):

As per [MochaJS's documentation on hooks](https://mochajs.org/#root-level-hooks):

- You can define any hook as a root level hook.

You should utilize `before()` as a root level hook for the problem you are facing.

From inside this hook you can call methods which are used for authentication. Mocha will wait for this `before()` block to complete before jumping to the execution of actual test cases.